# Google Places search - default value

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a form I'm using to capture a location (Place ID) on a Google map.

I'm using Google's Place ID selector. Code is below or here https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xfsw89po/

If I have a Place ID I want to use as the default value when the map is first loaded, how can I do this?

(I can see how I can default the position of the map using lat/long but I want to load it up with a default Place ID first).

```
// This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
// for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
// the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
// selected.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    });
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
        'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
        place.formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

I've googled but can't seem to find any examples of this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the place Details Service to get the coordinates of the PlaceId and use those to center the map, or use the viewport returned by the request to center and zoom the map.

For example, using Place Id: `ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE` (the Empire State Building), the below request will center and zoom the map to fit the viewport for that result from the Place Details Service.

```
  const request = {
    placeId: "ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE", // Empire State Building
    fields: ["name", "formatted_address", "place_id", "geometry"],
  };
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
    if (
      status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK &&
      place &&
      place.geometry &&
      place.geometry.location
    ) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport)
        // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
        marker.setPlace({
          placeId: place.place_id,
          location: place.geometry.location
        });
        marker.setVisible(true);

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
          'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
          place.formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xfsw89po/4/)

[updated proof of concept with marker](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xfsw89po/5/)

[image: screenshot with added marker and infowindow]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
// for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
// the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
// selected.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
  const request = {
    placeId: "ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE", // Empire State Building
    fields: ["name", "formatted_address", "place_id", "geometry"],
  };
  const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
    if (
      status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK &&
      place &&
      place.geometry &&
      place.geometry.location
    ) {
      // map.setCenter(place.geometry.location),
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport)
      // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
      marker.setPlace({
        placeId: place.place_id,
        location: place.geometry.location
      });
      marker.setVisible(true);

      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
        'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
        place.formatted_address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    });
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
      'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
      place.formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

.controls {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```